# What happens if two components import the same CSS file in React?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have two React components:

```
import { React } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function ComponentA() {
  ...
}
export default ComponentA;
```

---

```
import { React } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function ComponentB() {
  ...
}
export default ComponentB;
```

Both of these components are importing the same CSS file `styles.css`. Now let's say that in my app, I'm importing both of these components, so **App.js** looks something like this:

```
import { ComponentA } from "./ComponentA";
import { ComponentB } from "./ComponentB";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What exactly happens here? Does my app import the same CSS file twice? And if so, do I just make the import on the `App.js` file instead?

Comment: Rather than managing styling by importing a specific CSS file, I'd recommend doing something like applying a class to your container based on the brand color selected, and then writing a single CSS file that applies specific styles based on the class

Comment: Your designer shouldn't organize CSS like that. He should merge all css files in one (specially for this purpose), and using CSS selectors. You can get different approaches with React and CSS. reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html, styled-components library is intuitive (updating css style following component's state and props). styled-components.com

Comment: @iqbalhossain Multiple source files get transpiled into a single one during the build process. If you're recommending that the *source* CSS be written all as one file, that sounds like it'd be quite a pain to manage. Easier to write it in separate files, keeping in mind folder structure, and let the build process combine it later. (Or use a completely different approach like styled components - yes, they're a nice alternative.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's as if it was only imported once.

When a module bundler like Webpack sees an `import`, it puts the following path in the list of files to process, *if the path doesn't exist already*. The file is only processed once, no matter how many times it's imported.

Note that with React apps, you will often see

```
import React from "react";
```

in tens or hundreds of files - React isn't created anew hundreds of times. Rather, the module is processed *once*, and then files that import it are given access to what React has exported.

Importing CSS files works the same way, in that they're only processed once no matter how many times an `import` exists for them (though they don't really have *exports*, just side-effects).

If both `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` depend on `styles.css`, feel free to keep importing `styles.css` in both - it doesn't hurt, and will make things easier to manage when you can see at a glance that both components directly depend on that CSS.